# MongoDb EMongoDocument YII, Collection Relation

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, relationship

I have 2 tables in MongoDb, Both are related to each other.

For example `Employee` and `Department`. `Employee` is related to `Department`.

```
Employee
{
    '_id' : ID_OF_EMPLOYEEE,
    'Name' : NAME_OF_EMPLOYEEE
    'dept_id' : ID_OF_EMPLOYEES_DEPT
}

DEPT
{
    '_id' : ID_OF_EMPLOYEEE,
    'Name' : NAME_OF_DEPT
}
```

Now, I want to create a YII Relation which will give me name of `Employee's` `Department`(Like what we do in Relation DB). it should look like

```
 $dept = $employee->department
```

Please give me a solution

Thanks.

Comment: What ext are you using? Is this Yii1 or Yii2?

Comment: Yii-1 + EmongoDocument